# Cucumber.json is empty in "afterAll" during execution

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-junit

In the "afterAll" section, I have a function that uses the "cucumber.json" file to generate a "TE" in Xray. However, I'm getting an error saying "Error parsing results file!" When I execute only the command that generates the "TE," it works fine. Therefore, I deduce that there is an issue during the execution. As a workaround, I added a 5-minute sleep, but within that time interval, the cucumber.json file remains empty (after executing the test features).

```
package com.runner;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;

import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.AfterAll;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;


import java.io.IOException;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty,html:target/cucumber-reports.html,json:target/cucumber.json")
//Could use Junit5 tags like @IncludeTags("Firefox|Chrome") etc
public class RunCucumberTest {

   @BeforeAll
   public static void frameworkSetup() throws Exception {
(confidencial data)
      //Xray
      XrayUtil.cargarVariablesDeAmbiente();
      XrayUtil.sincronizarFetaures();
   }

   @Before(order=0)
   public void scenarioSetup(Scenario scenario) {
      (confidencial functions)
   }

   @After(order=100)
   public void scenarioTearDown(Scenario scenario) {
      (confidencial functions)
   }

   @AfterAll
   public static void frameworkFinalTasks() throws IOException, ParseException, InterruptedException {
      LogHandler.writeSuiteLog();
      Thread.sleep(300000);
      XrayUtil.generarInfoJson();
      XrayUtil.enviarReporte();

   }
}
```

my pom dependency

```
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
         <version>4.5.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
         <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
         <version>4.5.0</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
         <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
         <version>4.5.0</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codoid.products/fillo -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
         <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
         <version>1.22</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20220320</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
         <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.9.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
         <artifactId>sshd-sftp</artifactId>
         <version>2.9.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- integracion xray dependecy -->




      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->

      <dependency>

         <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>

         <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>

         <version>1.1.1</version>

      </dependency>




      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.cdimascio/java-dotenv -->

      <dependency>

         <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>

         <artifactId>java-dotenv</artifactId>

         <version>5.2.2</version>

      </dependency>



   </dependencies>
```